# Export Data Table with related tables "integrity constraint violated"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I would like to export data with expdp.
Only 1 table (called tour) with data and all the related table data.

I export it in this way.

expdp whweb10/whweb10 directory=dump_dir dumpfile=remoteexport.dmp logfile=remoteexport.log network_link=wamaslink tables=tour VERSION=10.1

Now when I import it I get this error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (WHWEB10.FK_TOUR_HOSTTOUR) violated - parent key not found
```

Since the table structure (schema) is pretty complicated and big , is there a way to export the tour table and all related tables automatically or do I have to specify all related tables in the export statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Use
INCLUDE=TABLE

This means only the tables would be included, but it includes all related objects too, such as constraints and triggers will be created for you when you use INCLUDE=TABLE when importing.